# Domain modeling using ontology, a special case

Tags: owl, modeling, ontology, domain-model, description-logic

Using description logic (and corresponding OWL-DL) Consider we have class `Meeting` which could be attended by a class `Professor`, so that:

```
couldBeAttendedBy domain Meeting
couldBeAttendedBy range Professor
```

and consider that a `Professor` could be an `Assistant` of another `Professor`:

```
assistantOf domain Professor
assistantOf range Professor
```

**Question:** *How can I -using Terminological Box axioms (TBox)- state that, if a `Meeting`  `couldBeAttendedBy` a `Professor`, then it `couldBeAttendedBy` anyone of his `Assistants`.*

Fro example, consider that:

```
Meeting(m)
Professor(f)
m couldBeAttendedBy f
as assistantOf f
```

I want to conclude that

```
m couldBeAttendedBy as
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a property chain, giving a definition of `couldBeAttendedBy` to accommodate your rule.

For example, if you are using Protégé, you need to define for `couldBeAttendedBy` the following:

`couldBeAttendedBy o  inverse (assistantOf)`

at the SuperProperty Of (Chain), which will appear as

`couldBeAttendedBy o  inverse (assistantOf) SubPropertyOf couldBeAttendedBy`

The case is easy and is exactly what property chains are made for. But if the chains become more sophisticated, they might become undecidable. For example, in S1 º S2 º S3 º ... º Sn ⊑ R, R can only be on the first or last place of the left side of the expression. Otherwise it won't be decidable. This is one of the restrictions to Regular RBoxes. And property chains, or more formally "General Role Inclusion" can only be decidable if applied to Regular RBoxes.